# Set to particular time for youtube video using YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm aware of using

> "&t=0m25s"

for setting the youtube video to 25 seconds from the beginning. But, can someone please help me to set the same feature using **YouTubePlayerSupportFragment**

Here is my code

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment playerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fl_video, playerFragment).commit();
        playerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                    player.play();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
                // YouTube error
                String errorMessage = error.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sure. Agreed. Thanks for making this point

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to solve this problem. There's something known as

> cueVideo()

function in YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.

```
player.cueVideo("QYw77aNGXnE", 92000);
```

NOTE : 92000 corresponds to 92 seconds (1 minute 32 seconds) as the value needs to be given in milliseconds.